# Why I am getting error while verifying file type?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I am want to capture the files which have type `image or video`. But according to my condition I can't understand why it is throwing error even for the correct file type. Below is my code:

**app.component.ts**

```
startUpload(event: FileList)
  {
    const file = event.item(0);
    if((file.type.split('/')[0] !== 'video') || (file.type.split('/')[0] !== 'image'))
    {
      alert(file.type.split('/')[0]);
      return;
    }
  }
```

While uploading video/image files it's showing video/image respectively in the alert box.
Please suggest me where I need to change.

Answer (score 0):

your logic is wrong. you can't have (x!==y) || (x!==b) because it will always be true.

you probably mean '&&' instead of '||' in your if statement

Answer (score 0):

Let me introduce you to [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). In plain words it states

- not (A or B) = not A and not B
- not (A and B) = not A or not B

Accordingly in your case you need to test if the file type is neither `'video'` nor `'image'`. So you could either do

```js
const fileType = file.type.split('/')[0];
if((fileType !== 'video') && (fileType !== 'image')) {
  alert(fileType);
  return;
}
```

or

```js
const fileType = file.type.split('/')[0];
if(!((fileType === 'video') || (fileType === 'image'))) {
  alert(fileType);
  return;
}
```